# Keycloak - MediaType not set on path

Tags: angular, keycloak

In **Keycloak** (Server Version **12.0.1**), when I try to reach a realm login page, these errors are triggered:

`09:44:04,737 ERROR [org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider] (default task-1)  MediaType not set on path /auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/auth, with response status 500`

`09:44:04,738 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/auth: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`

This is the URL generated clicking on Login button on web page (Angular ):

```
https://auth.<project-name>.local:5001/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<client-id>&state=MWl1SkQwNE1vaXZ1LXdLVGh6MWhvZGJiVldPVy40RTJwU2pVfmZ5ZzhsTmRZ&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F<realm-name>%3A4288%2F&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access%20<clientId>&code_challenge=OPHLi0y4cM0BtILP12xVwUH8p_SiJZjZx1c_ehsFwB4&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=MWl1SkQwNE1vaXZ1LXdLVGh6MWhvZGJiVldPVy40RTJwU2pVfmZ5ZzhsTmRZ
```

**Angular project**

***auth.service.ts***

```
public configure() {
authConfig.issuer = this.settingsService.getBaseAuthUrl()}auth/realms/${this._window.location.hostname.split('.')[0]}`;
`this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
```

***auth.config.ts***

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
 
  // skipIssuerCheck: null,
  // Url of the Identity Provider
  // issuer: `${authUrl}auth/realms/master`,

  redirectUri: document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href as string,

  
  clientId: '<clientId>',
  
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access <clientId>',

  requireHttps: true,

  showDebugInformation: true,

  responseType: 'code',

  disableAtHashCheck: false    

};
```

### **SOLUTION**

I solved this problem setting the `LoginTheme: keycloak` in realm settings.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from resetting the LoginTheme to the default `keycloak` theme as you did, if there is already another theme set and you want to keep it, make sure the theme's files are present in `keycloak/themes/<the_custom_theme_name_here>/login/`, otherwise you'll get the error you mentionned. You may need to restart Keycloak after copying the theme files to their folder if your setup is set to cache the themes.

Comment: I have done the same, but still i am getting the same error when i try to change login to my custom theme. Is there any repo that you have referred?

Comment: There is no repo.  Have you double-checked the content of your theme files? (I presume these were working previously?)  Have you copied your theme files to the appropriate folder, and if so have you restarted Keycloak after copying them there?  If the files are valid and copied in the right folder, you may be able to select that theme after the restart.

Comment: I found the solution. I was trying by using the docker copy command. But it works only when we do volume mounting. There is one repo which i found very useful for theme files. https://github.com/genny-project/keycloak-themes